# Divergence of $\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{2^{r_{n}}r_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{r_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a nondecreasing sequence of positive $r_{n}$  such that $$\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{2^{r_{n}}r_{n}}=\infty.$$If $s_n=\lceil{r_{n}}\rceil$ then show that $\sum_{n}\dfrac{1}{2^{s_{n}}s_{n}}$ also diverges.

When $r_{n}\rightarrow r$ finite, then this is true because $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{2^{s_{n}}s_{n}}\ne 0.$$ I am not able to give an argument for $r_{n}\rightarrow \infty$ case. Probably the  divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{n\log_2 n}$ is useful here but cannot see how.

Thank you.

Comment: If $ r_n \geq 1$, then $ 2^{s_n} s_n  < 2^{r_n + 1}  (r_n + 1) < 4 \cdot 2^{r_n} r_n$